# OpenCV : algorithm for simple image rotation and reduction

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv, rotation

I have tried image rotation and reduction(JPEG) with `getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);`
and `warpAffine(image1, image3, rotation, image3.size());`
I got the result I wanted(image as below)
[image]

```
for (int r = 0;r < image1.rows;r++) {

    for (int c = r + 1;c < image1.cols;c++) {
        Point center  = Point(image1.cols / 2, image1.rows / 2);
        Point center1 = Point(image1.cols / 2, image1.rows / 2);
        double angle = 90.0;
        double scale = 1;
        double angle1 = 90.0;
        double scale1 = 0.5;
        rotation = getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);
        rotation1 = getRotationMatrix2D(center1, angle1, scale1);
```

but I want to learn some simple rotation and reduction algorithm ( simple for beginner like me )  without using any library
to get the same result.
After searching for various solutions, i ended up with this
[image]
from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67613/how-can-i-rotate-a-bitmap-without-d3d-or-opengl
Can anyone break up bit by bit of the simple  linear algebra to explain to me in regards to my pesudo code?

EDIT:
Reduction code

```
      void reduction(Mat image1)
   {
        for (int r = 0;r < imgC.rows;r++)
        {
        for (int c = 0;c < imgC.cols;c++)
    {


        int new_x = c * (125 / 256);
        int new_y = r * (125 / 256);
        imgC.at<uchar>(r, c) = imgC.at<uchar>(new_y, new_x);
        }
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example I have loaded two images. One is in gray scale and other is color image. Both are same image so you can understand easily how to handle rotation with mathematical equation. Please see this example which is very easy to understand. Also in the similar manner you can add scaling and reduction. Here each point is converted according to the equation and color value set on new location. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define PIPI 3.14156

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("C:/Users/dell2/Desktop/DSC00587.JPG",0);//loading gray scale image
    Mat imgC = imread("C:/Users/dell2/Desktop/DSC00587.JPG",1);//loading color image

    Mat rotC(imgC.cols, imgC.rows, imgC.type());
    rotC = Scalar(0,0,0);

    Mat rotG(img.cols, img.rows, img.type());
    rotG = Scalar(0,0,0);

    float angle = 90.0 * PIPI / 180.0;

    for(int r=0;r<imgC.rows;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<imgC.cols;c++)
        {
            float new_px = c * cos(angle) - r * sin(angle);
            float new_py = c * sin(angle) + r * cos(angle);

            Point pt((int)-new_px, (int)new_py);

            //color image
            rotC.at<Vec3b>(pt) = imgC.at<Vec3b>(r,c);//assign color value at new location from original image

            //gray scale image
            rotG.at<uchar>(pt) = img.at<uchar>(r,c);//assign color value at new location from original image

        }
    }


    imshow("color",rotC);
    imshow("gray",rotG);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Though is this code able to support only 90 degree? As I had tried entering various other amount such as (180 degree ,270 degree )but it just gives me error. What is "-" sign for -new_px?

Comment: -ve sign is due to x value gets negative, it is okay for normal co-ordinate system. But in image processing you know the top, left point is (0,0) and bottom, right point is (w,h)...for custom angle it would be complicated as you need to calculate the angle as well as image dimension. if rotate 45 Degree and want to fit the rotated image under same canvas size, then you must need to scale down the image. Also for 90,270 Degree image dimension will swap. Usually image dimension kept same and scale down the rotated image to fit under the canvas

Comment: oh, thank you for your answer, I just added in my reduction code ( edited post ) and it doesn't work, what mistake have I made?

Comment: Didn't assign pixel value. Just calculated the point. U should assign pixel value in new location of the output mat

Comment: why did you use Mat rotC(img.cols, img.rows, img.type()); 
instead of using Mat rotC;

would you kindly explain it to me?