# C++ opencv : rotating image by an arbitrary number (degree)

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv, rotation

From my previous post,
[OpenCV : algorithm for simple image rotation and reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275340/opencv-algorithm-for-simple-image-rotation-and-reduction)

I still could not rotate my image by an arbitrary number but only 90 degree.
I have changed my code since then, right now is

```
   Mat image1 = imread("Balloon.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
   Mat rotC(image1.cols, image1.rows, image1.type());
   #define PI 3.14156
void rotation(Mat image1)
{
    int hwidth = image1.rows / 2;
    int hheight = image1.cols / 2;
    double angle = 45.00 * PI / 180.0;

    for (int x = 0;x < image1.rows;x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < image1.cols;y++) {


        int xt = x - hwidth;
        int yt = y - hheight;


        int xs = (int)round((cos(angle) * xt - sin(angle) * yt) + hwidth);
        int ys = (int)round((sin(angle) * xt + cos(angle) * yt) + hheight); 

         rotC.at<Vec3b>(x,y) = image1.at<Vec3b>(xs, ys);

      }
    }
 }



  int main()
{
 rotation(image1);
 imshow("color", rotC);
 waitKey(0);
}
```

An error came out at `rotC.at<Vec3b>(x,y) = image1.at<Vec3b>(xs, ys);`

is this the only part where my code have error? 
I'm trying to link back my result into the new rotation then display it with imshow.
Please let me know what I'll need to do in order to make it rotate with an arbitrary number such as 30 degree, 46 degree etc.

The result of I wanted to get is shown below, the image is rotated via opencv function.
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: Check that `xs` and `ys` are actually inside the image

Comment: you should better create a rotation matrix (cos, -sin, 0; sin, cos, 0) and use the openCV function warpAffine which will probably result in being less error prone, more efficient and gives you more interpolation possibilities.

Comment: ah wait, that matrix would rotate around (0,0) so better use getRotationMatrix2D and then warpAffine.

Comment: @Miki Sorry but how do you check if it is inside the image? I have already put it in the inner loop

Comment: @Micka yes thats my code for opencv function ( code is in the image) but now i'm trying to manually rotate it by an arbitrary angle without using getrotationmartrix2D

Comment: Yes, but the values assigned to `xs,ys` may be outside the image boundary. Just check that `0 <= xs < img.cols` and `0 <= ys < img.rows`

Comment: @Miki ahh thank you so much! 
i added  `if  (xs >= 0 && xs < image1.rows && ys >= 0 && ys < image1.cols)` and my program works. Appreciated your help! really! Didn't know that it will be outside of the image boundary..

Comment: I would like to ask a beginner question,
why is it that if i change  Mat rotC(image1.cols, image1.rows, image1.type());
into Mat rotC;
i will get an error?
Been bothering me :l